# Data set in the React state returned from Firebase is always null

Tags: javascript, reactjs

I have an issue getting data for my inventoryDetails variable. It is always null before the rendering is completed. I cannot read the itemName from the inventoryDetails set by the Firebase call. I get the warning shown below.

> Uncaught TypeError: Cannot destructure property 'itemName' of 'inventoryDetails' as it is null.

#### Code

```
export default function InventoryDetails() {
 const inventoryId = useParams();
 const [inventoryDetails, setInventoryDetails] = useState(null);
 const getData = async () => {
   const inventoryCollectionRef = doc(db, "inventory", inventoryId.id); // reference to the collection
  try {
     const docSnap = await getDoc(inventoryCollectionRef);
     console.log(docSnap.data());
     return docSnap.data();
  } catch (error) {
     console.log(error);
  }
};
useEffect(() => {
  getData().then((data) => setInventoryDetails(data));
}, []);

const { itemName } = inventoryDetails; //
```

Comment: As a final note: I'm not sure how salvageable this question is. Based on the answer, it seems like closing this question for being caused by a typo, is appropriate.

Comment: Actually, the answer is not a typo. I need to use useState({}) instead of useState(null). Object {} data type must be used to prevent the abovementioned problem.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> it is always null

Yes, because it's explicitly defined like that:

```
const [inventoryDetails, setInventoryDetails] = useState(null);
```

If you want it to be an object, you can make it one:

```
const [inventoryDetails, setInventoryDetails] = useState({});
```

Or perhaps even give it a default for the property you're looking for:

```
const [inventoryDetails, setInventoryDetails] = useState({ itemName: '' });
```

Alternatively, you can change your destructuring operation to handle a `null` value, for example:

```
const itemName = inventoryDetails?.itemName;
```

But what you *can't* do is destructure any properties from `null` or `undefined`.

Comment: `itemName = ''` should be `itemName: ''`

Comment: @Undo: I honestly have no idea why I did that.  I must have C# on the brain.  Thanks!

Comment: Thank you! I set it to useState({}) instead of useState(null), and it works now.